# Диапазоны в операторах switch/case

Tags: c, c++

Можно написать проверку условия на принадлежность переменной диапазону величин, например:

```
if (0 < i && i < 10) {
    // ...
}
```

Можно ли сделать похожую проверку для операторов switch/case без перечисления case'ов внутри switch'а?

```
switch (i) {
    case 1: 
        // ...
    break;

    // ...

    case 9: 
        // ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: так можно делать в Паскале/делфи:)

Answer (score 6):

Нет, нельзя. Можно так для небольших интервалов величин:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
       // ...
    break;
}
```

Обратите внимание, между последовательными выборами `case` нет оператора `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то аналог

```
if (0 < i && i < 10) {
    // ...
}
```

с помощью switch/case можно сделать так:

```
switch (0 < i && i < 10)
{
    case true: //...
}
```

P.S.:
Для GCC есть расширение, позволяющее делать диапазоны, например:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 0 ... 10: 
       // ...; 
       break;
}
```

Comment: +1 за упоминание расширения GCC (к слову, оно также есть и в Clang). Но вот первый вариант `switch (0 < i && i < 10)` — это какой-то сюр.